# How To Get Data From Array Into Variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to get data from an array created using file_get_contents. The file is an ADIF (*.adi) which is the output of ham radio logging software which logs contacts made on ham radio.

This is the file.

http://www.wildragon.com/StackOverflow.adi

What I need to extract is the value of <"call:6"> which in this case is ZL3DAC and this is the value I need to work with. "call" is the callsign of the station worked and "6" is the number of characters in the value.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
$fileToRead = // is defined earlier in the script.
function goBack() // is defined earlier in the script.

if (file_get_contents($fileToRead)) {
    echo "<br/>\nSuccess.";
} else {
    echo "<br/>\nFailed to read ADI.";
    goBack();
    die();
}
$array = explode("<EOR>", $x);
sscanf ($x, "<CALL:%d>%s ",$length,$rawcall);
$callsign = substr($rawcall,0,$length);
print_r($callsign);
```

I'm getting "Success" for the file_get_contents function, but I'm not getting any result for print_r($callsign);

What am I doing wrong please, and what do I need to do to make this work please?

Comment: Try to use [this](https://bitbucket.org/kj4iwx/phpadifparser/wiki/Home). It will make your job easy.

Comment: jagad89, thank you for the link. I've been trying to work with that for a few days now with no success. I appreciate that you found that so quickly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to why this doesn't work is because `sscanf()` attempts to match from the *beginning* of the string. So in order to parse the string with the function you must first use some simple string manipulation.

Get the contents of the file to parse.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
```

First we search for the position of the string 'call:' using `strpos()`.
Then we take the sub-string starting from the found position and forward using `substr()`.

```
$temporary = substr($contents, strpos($contents, 'call:'));
```

With the example data you provided the variable temporary has the
value of: `call:6>ZL3DAC <cont:2>OC <country:11>New Zealand...` until the end of the data string.

We can then calculate the position of the next opening tag. This assumes a opening tag is an entry for different data and we should therefore be past the data we want.

Now we can extract the sub-string once more. This string should only contain the data we want.

```
$string = substr($temporary, 0, strpos($temporary, '<'));
```

Since `sscanf()` returns an array with the amount of placeholder defined in the same order if no optional parameters are provided. As the `sscanf()` requires the optional parameters to be parsed as references I have used `list()` as it saves us from using references (references does not use variable optimization).

```
list($length, $callsign) = sscanf($string, "call:%d>%s");
```

Using the sample data you provided the variable `$callsign` contains the value of `ZL3DAC` and variable `$length` the value of `6`.

**Alternative**

You could also use a regular expression. Regexes are slow compared to other tasks, but because we have to do so much work beforehand I think a regex is acceptable here. The code for such solution could be.

```
$matches = [];
if(preg_match('~<call:(\d+)>(\w+)~', $contents, $matches) == false) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Could not match callsign from input string.');
}
```

Since `preg_match` populates the first element in `$matches` with the matched string we also get the raw source. We can then extract the values into variables as above.

With raw string:

```
list($raw, $length, $callsign) = $matches;
```

Without raw string:

```
list($length, $callsign) = array_slice($matches, 1);
```

**Fetching multiple values with a regular expression**

You can utilize the regular expression function `preg_match_all()` with the same regex as above. You will also need to add the flag `PREG_SET_ORDER` to easier extract the result sets. Using [this](http://www.wildragon.com/StackOverflow_2.adi) sample data an example could be:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('~<call:(\d+)>(\w+)~', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

This will result in `$matches` containing an array of:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '<call:10>ZL100ANZAC' (length=19)
      1 => string '10' (length=2)
      2 => string 'ZL100ANZAC' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '<call:5>H44MS' (length=13)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => string 'H44MS' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '<call:6>SV9CVY' (length=14)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => string 'SV9CVY' (length=6)
```

Where the first element is the raw matched string. The second the length of the callsign and the third the callsign itself.

Happy coding!

Comment: AnotherGuy, thank you so much! Your first solution worked instantly, you're a very clever guy. I didn't even bother trying the alternative. Now I have that working, I need to get more data from this file, and from similar files with multiple lines (records). I'll see how I go, but I've got a starting point now. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I'm stuck again, please help.

Now I'm trying to pull all the callsigns from a file with multiple records but I'm not even getting any returned. Is there an easy way to make this work over multiple lines please?

Here is an example file.

http://www.wildragon.com/StackOverflow_2.adi

Comment: @WiLDRAGoN - I would use my alternative solution and switch to using preg_match_all(). You cannot extract the different values with list() this time though. You can inspect the return value with var_dump() and I am sure you can figure out the rest by yourself

Comment: I wish I was as sure as you that I can figure it out myself. I've come up with this, but now I'm getting multiple results when the same callsign is matched. I only want to return unique matches.

`$matches = [];
$callsign = (preg_match_all('~<call:(\d+)>(\w+)~', $contents, $matches));
foreach ($matches[0] as $callsign) {
 echo "<br/>\n$callsign";
}`

Comment: Give me some time and I can update the answer. It may be a while though :D

Comment: Mate, thank you so much for your time, I really appreciate it. You brought me one step closer to what I was trying to achieve but I'm realising this project is way above my capabilities. My knowledge of PHP and HTML is very, very basic. I've taken on this project on behalf of a small non-profit amateur radio club with no budget for this project, but I think we're going to have to consider paying someone to do this for us. I've taken up enough of your time, but if in fact you do have time on your hands, the following is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Let's say the data in the sample file was doubled up (I copy the 3 records and paste them at the end of the file), resulting in the 3 records being duplicated. Like this... [link](http://www.wildragon.com/StackOverflow_3.adi) Using the code in my previous post, it echos ZL100ANZAC H44MS SV9CVY ZL100ANZAC H44MS SV9CVY. I don't want to echo duplicates, only uniques, so I want it to echo the following. ZL100ANZAC H44MS SV9CVY . I'm about halfway through the script and the simple stuff is done, but I've obviously reached the difficult part now and I appreciate you helping me get there.

Comment: If you can create an array with only the callsigns you can use the native `array_unique()` function. It should filter out any duplicates easily. Browse around stackoverflow or create a new question, because this is beginning to stray to far from the original question :D